# retornar valor booleano de un observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, rxjs

Como hago para que esta funcion retorne un valor verdadero o falso

```
autenticacion(token: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(
        this.apiUrl + "autenticacion",
        { token },
        { headers: this.headers }
    ).pipe(map(data => data));
}

verificacion(){
    let bool;
    this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(data=>{
      if(data.data.token==this.auth.getToken()){
        bool=true;
      }else{
        bool=false;
      }
    });
    console.log(bool);
    return bool;
}

canactive(){
   this.verificacion();
}
```

cuando llamo la funcion compruebo que me devuelve con el console log pero me devuelve un valor undefined alguien sabe como hacer que me retorne el false o el true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion a mi problema fue retornar un observable y el canactive que lo recibe volverlo un metodo observable

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){

    return new Observable<boolean>( observer => {

      if(this.auth.isLoggednIn() && this.auth.isLoggednRol()){

        if(this.auth.getRol()==route.data['privileges']){

          this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(data => {
            if(data.data.token == this.auth.getToken()) {
              observer.next(true);
            } else {
              observer.next(false);
            }
          })

        }else{
          this.route.navigate(['/']);
          observer.next(false);
        }

    }else{
      this.route.navigate(['/']);
      observer.next(false);
    }

  });

}

}
```

Comment: Te sobra algo de código ahí... no necesitas crear un nuevo observable

Answer (score 2):

Primero debes de entender sobre contextos asíncronos.

```
this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).**subscribe(data=>{
      if(data.data.token==this.auth.getToken()){
        bool=true;
      }else{
        bool=false;
      }
    });**
```

Esta llamada es asíncrona por ende no se cambiará el valor de `bool` durante la ejecución de tu método "autenticacion" sino cuando el observable sea resuelto ( cuando obtenga el token) y ya para ese entonces la ejecución de tu método habrá pasado e impreso "undefined", pues "bool" todavía no se le ha asignado ningún valor.

Lo que puedes hacer: Retornar el observable y que el código que llame a "autenticacion" sea quien decida que hacer cuando se obtenga el token.

Para referencia de cómo usar un observables y suscripciones:
https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/practica-observables-angular.html

Para entender los contextos asíncronos:
https://lemoncode.net/lemoncode-blog/2018/1/29/javascript-asincrono

Comment: como retorno ese observable ?

Comment: Podrias poner el metodo desde el cual llamas this.autenticacion()? Ese es el metodo que debe llamar  this.auth.autenticacion y manejar el observable, asi como lo manejas en ese metodo de "autenticacion".  Ahora que leo de nuevo tu codigo, creo que te vvendria bien leer sobre "guards" en Angular. Creo que eso es lo que quieres lograr, proteger tus rutas de usuarios que no esten "logueados".

Comment: actualize la pregunta, yo en este metodo de autenticacion traigo un token y lo comparo con un que tengo en localstore. este devuelve verdadero o falso lo que necesito es que me retorne ese valor dentro del guard. cosa que no puedo hacer por que el observable no me retorna valor alguno

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a analizar lo que tienes, que no tiene mala pinta:

```
autenticacion(token: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(
        this.apiUrl + "autenticacion",
        { token },
        { headers: this.headers }
    ).pipe(map(data => data));
}
```

Este primer método realiza una petición POST para logarse en el sistema. Tiene buen aspecto, pero te sobra la llamada a map, que no hace nada, podrías dejarlo así:

```
autenticacion(token: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Usuario>(
        this.apiUrl + "autenticacion",
        { token },
        { headers: this.headers });
}
```

Pasemos al siguiente método, donde empezamos a ver problemas (ver comentarios):

```
verificacion(){
    let bool; //declaras la variable que quieres devolver

    // Llamas al método anterior y te suscribes...  
    this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).subscribe(data=>{
      if(data.data.token==this.auth.getToken()){
        bool=true;
      }else{
        bool=false;
      }
    });
    //cuando llegamos aquí, la llamada aún no tiene respuesta!!
    console.log(bool); //siempre será undefined
    return bool;
}
```

Vamos a intentar arreglar esto, pasaremos a tener un método que devuelve un `Observable<boolean>`:

```
//añadimos el tipo a devolver, que siempre ayuda
verificacion(): Observable<boolean> {
     // Llamas al método anterior y con `pipe` y `map` añadimos una transformación
    return this.auth.autenticacion(this.auth.getToken()).pipe(
      map(data => data.data.token == this.auth.getToken());
}


canactive(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.verificacion(); //devuelve el resultado de la verificación
}
```